# different types of null in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a method that looks like this:

```
static UserEvent get(long userId, long eventId) {
     UserEvent.find 'from UserEvent where user.id=:userId and event.id=:eventId',
            [userId: userId, eventId: eventId]
}
```

I'm calling it two times with some test data:

```
    println UserEvent.get(1, 1) //I know this has value
    println UserEvent.get(1,2) //I know this does not
```

The above two statements result in:

```
scheduler.UserEvent : null
null
```

**Question**

What is the difference? How can I write an If condition for when something is present or not..

**Update**

I'm creating the object like this:

```
def event = Events.findById(params.eventid)
def user = User.findById(params.userid)

UserEvent.create(user, event, true)
```

Comment: Have you overridden the `toString` method in `UserEvent`?

Comment: no I haven't. My UserEvent method looks like a class from spring security plugin:

Comment: But it looks like it's pulling back a `UserEvent` object (as expected) in the first instance, but when it prints it out, it's printing some property of it which is set to null

Comment: This is exactly what my class looks like: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/templates/PersonAuthority.groovy.template

Comment: can i modify my method so that it returns a number greater than 0 (depending on how many records were found) or return -1 if nothing is found

Comment: Looks like the object it is finding has no `ID` for some reason then.  How are you creating them?

Answer (score 1):

@tim_yates is right, the object that is retrieved doesn't have an id property. Looks like an M to M relationship.

So in the first case an instance is being returned but it's ID is null.
In the second case the object isn't found.

You can use something like:

```
def ue = UserEvent.get(userId, eventId)
if (ue && ue instanceof UserEvent) { //do something } 
else { //do something else }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first case returns an instance of UserEvent, which inside of an if statement, should return true. The second case returns null, which inside of an if statement, should return false.