# How to use this get method from my groovy class in a GSP

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm following the template of [this groovy class](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/templates/PersonAuthority.groovy.template) from the spring security plugin to maintain my many-to-many relationsips.

One of the methods is like this:

```
static UserEvent get(long userId, long eventId) {
    UserEvent.find 'from UserRole where user.id=:userId and event.id=:eventId',
            [userId: userId, eventId: eventId]
}
```

Note: This class doesn't have an ID property.

**Question**

How can I use this method from my GSP to verify whether its returning something or not?

I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work, it always gives me the same result:

```
<g:if test="${UserEvent.get(currentUserId as long, eventInstance.id as long) != null} ">
   <span>you attended this event</span>
</g:if>
```

This if seems to be true for both cases, when I have an entry in the UserEvent class or when I don't.

Comment: A custom taglib would be a way better approach here and way more testable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the work in the controller and pass the data to the view. The view should only be concerned with displaying data, not computing it and especially not doing database queries. This isn't PHP :)

Add the code to the controller action:

```
def yourAction() {
   // existing code

   UserEvent event = UserEvent.get(currentUserId as long, eventInstance.id as long)

   [foo: bar, ..., eventExists: event != null]
}
```

And then use it in the GSP:

```
<g:if test="${eventExists}">
   <span>you attended this event</span>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Or do it in a taglib if you need to reuse this in your views.

Comment: I wanted to do this in the controller but `events` is a list. So, I didn't know how to inject an additional property to it. I'll ask that as a separate question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141202/how-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-groovy-and-add-property-for-each-object is the question i asked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you get rid of the null test, and just rely on groovy truth?

```
<g:if test="${UserEvent.get(currentUserId as long, eventInstance.id as long)}">
```

Comment: That seems to be returning true all the time.

Comment: So does `UserEvent.get` always return something?

Comment: From my understanding it should NOT. Anyway, I modified the if tag to this and it seems to work: `<g:if test="${scheduler.UserEvent.get(currentUserId as long, eventInstance.id as long)?.eventId != null}">` btw tim, this post is related to the previous question I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091570/different-types-of-null-in-groovy

Comment: "From my understanding it should NOT": You realize that you should be able to answer tim_yates' question, right?  Tests?  Just executing that query?  Both would tell you whether or not your code should be working as expected.