# How to iterate over a list in groovy and add property for each object

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a list of events like so:

events = Events.all

`Events` have a many-to-many relationship with `Users` via class `UserEvents` modeled after the [approach from spring-security-plugin](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/templates/PersonAuthority.groovy.template):

I would like to find out whether a `User` is attending an `Event` and I can do that by running this:

```
UserEvent.get(currentUserId, eventId)
```

**Question**

How can I do this over all the elements of my list `events` so that in my view layer I can easily find out whether `currentUserId` is going to the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for all of the associated `User`s for an `Event` like this:

```
def user = ...
def events = UserEvent.findAllByUser(user).event
```

This is a fairly efficient query since it executes SQL similar to

```
select * from user_event where user_id=?
```

and then loads each `Event`. This is N+1 though since it loads each Event individually, so you can do it more efficiently with this:

```
def eventIds = UserEvent.findAllByUser(user).eventId
def events = Event.getAll(eventIds)
```

The first line just gets the event ids using the same SQL as above, then the second line runs SQL like

```
select * from event where id in (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

Comment: What if `eventIds` is empty in the line `Event.getAll(eventIds)` - This results in a sql error whenever `eventIds` is an empty list

Comment: Use `def events = eventIds ? Event.getAll(eventIds) : []` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a subset of your events which the user attends, then go with what Burt Beckwith sugeested.

But, if you need the whole set of events and just add an attribute you should use metaClass.

```
event.metaClass.userAttends= ...
```

*you can see explanations about metaClass [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses)*

Specifically in your situation i would get all ids as Burt Beckwith said and the check for each event if its id is in the list:

```
def eventIds = UserEvent.findAllByUser(user).eventId
expandedEvents = events.collect {event-> 
   event.metaClass.usetAttends = eventIds.contains(event.id)
   return event}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`grep()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#grep%28java.lang.Object%29) to filter the list of events by whether `UserEvent.get()` returns an item.

```
events.grep { UserEvent.get(currentUserId, it.id) }
```